# VBA looping and pasting to new worksheet

Tags: vba, loops

HI, 
i have data of this structure :

User   |  Channels

1      | 12391  | 123123 | 122121

2      | 91283 | 1239871| 12731| 1231982|128317

3|

4| 1231

5| 19881|19288

how can i use vba to tranpose this data set into a new sheet such that the result is:

User | Channel

1      | 12391

1 | 123123

1 | 122121

2      | 91283

2| 1239871

2| 12731

2| 1231982

Comment: i have tried it in SQL. because it has alot null values, it cannot import data into the server correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
''you want, but it is very convenient for notes
''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
''can be used.
''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

''Late binding, so no reference is needed

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


cn.Open strCon

''This example list the fields by name (HDR=Yes)
''and only the first two columns have names (User, Channels) 
''so F3,F4 etc are automatically assigned to the unnamed columns

''It would not be difficult to select everything from the relevant 
''sheet and loop through that to build the Union query.
strSQL = "SELECT [User], Channels " _
       & "FROM [Sheet1$] " _
       & "WHERE Channels Is Not Null " _
       & "UNION ALL " _
       & "SELECT [User], F3 " _
       & "FROM [Sheet1$] " _
       & "WHERE F3 Is Not Null "
''And so on

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3


''Pick a suitable empty worksheet for the results

 Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

 ''Tidy up
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 cn.Close
 Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: i;m trying to do a loop for each row in column A, and in each row, Ctrl-Shift Right, paste as tranpose in new worksheet

Comment: Perhaps you do not understand the point of the SQL statement in the example above?